# Cannot center text with HTML5/CSS

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying simply to center text horizontally in a form as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <div id="contact-form">  
       <head-black>STEWARD'S WEEKLY REPORT</head-black><br>
   </div>  
</html>
```

contents of style.css:

```
#contact-form {  
    background-color:#F2F7F9;  
    width:925px;  
    padding:10px;  
    margin: 10px auto;      
    border: 6px solid #8FB5C1;  
    -moz-border-radius:25px;  
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;  
    border-radius:15px;  
    position:relative;  
}  

#contact-form head-black {  
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:14px;  
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The text stays left aligned.

Answer (score 6):

`<head-black>` is non-standard HTML syntax. Use of custom tags [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/when-to-use-custom-html-tags). Instead, use:

```
<h1 class="head-black">STEWARD'S WEEKLY REPORT</h1>
```

and CSS:

```
#contact-form {  
    background-color:#F2F7F9;  
    width:925px;  
    padding:10px;  
    margin: 10px auto;      
    border: 6px solid #8FB5C1;  
    -moz-border-radius:25px;  
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;  
    border-radius:15px;  
    position:relative;
    text-align:center; /* put this here */
}  

#contact-form .head-black {  
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:14px;  
    text-decoration:underline;   
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MqH4G/1/)

**Edit**

If you'd like to center only the `<h1>`, simply set it to `display: block`, and set the `text-align: center` in the h1 tag. Don't forget to **remove the `text-align: center` from the #content-form CSS block**. Do the following to the `.head-black` CSS:

```
#contact-form .head-black {  
    display:block;
    font-size:14px;  
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

The jsfiddle above shows the new changes.

Comment: Your solution is great. However your argument that <head-black> is not a valid tag is 'misinformed'. HTML does allow custom tags and theres no rule that do not disallow it. So if your only edit you css that wold have served as a solution.

Comment: You make a good point. I'll update my answer accordingly. However, using custom tags is not good practice in my opinion, so I can't condone it. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/when-to-use-custom-html-tags) also

Comment: I made the changes above and  anything that gets written is now centered, where I only wanted the one line centered.

Comment: @BrianPhillips, how do you add custom tags to HTML? Most if not all browsers will ignore unknown tags. I tried it in Chrome and Opera and a tag of mycustom works fine but isn't this NOT standard HTML anymore?

Comment: Doesn't the advent of web components invalidate the opinion that custom tags are poor practice?